# Function delivers value, before ajax request changed it

Tags: javascript, oop, global-variables

I am running an ajax request to retrieve a value of either 0,1, or 2 based upon some mysql code in the "check_answer_status.php" file. For test purposes, I have included the alert to check whether the general ajax and mysql request works fine and it does, hence the value contained within "Questiions.answerStatus" at the time of the alert is correct. However, my problem is that the function "checkAnswerStatus" has already executed and did not change the inital value of "answerStatus" (which I set to 50 for test purposes).

Context: sometime later in the code I want to execute code dependent on the value of the variable "answerStatus".

I believe I need to somehow include something like an "oncomplete" or something comparable, but I do not know how to do that. Can anyone help me out? Many thanks!

```
var = Questions = {

answerStatus:50,

checkAnswerStatus : function(question){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            test = xmlhttp.responseText;
            Questions.answerStatus = test;
            alert(Questions.answerStatus);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../../include/check_answer_status.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("q="+question);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you make is asynchronus (the third parameter of the xmlhttp.open function). If you changed it to:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","../../include/check_answer_status.php",false);
```

it should work.

Another options is to pass a callback to your checkAnswerStatus function, and call the callback when the request finishes. Example:

```
checkAnswerStatus : function(question, callback){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            test = xmlhttp.responseText;
            Questions.answerStatus = test;
            callback(Questions.answerStatus); //call the function
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../../include/check_answer_status.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("q="+question);
}
```

and then you will call the function like this:

```
Questions.checkAnswerStatus("bla bla", function(answerStatus) {
   alert(answerStatus);
});
```

Comment: No problem:) I believe the second solution is much better, because the whole application wont freeze when you make requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Nemos answer I would recommend you read following resources from MDN:

More technical API documentation for a brief overview of all the possibilities:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

More real life usecases:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Hope this helps